# How can I filter out closed leads in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I have a batch Apex job where I want to query a bunch of leads.

How can I filter out already closed leads from the SOQL query?

I would think something like

```
[SELECT ... FROM Lead__c WHERE leadStatus != 'Closed']
```

would work but I don't know the exact way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by closed, you mean converted, you can use the `isConverted` field, e.g.

```
[select id,name from lead where isConverted=false]
```